# Am i right ? - C expression

Tags: c, expression

```
int *(*(*P)[2][2])(int,int);
```

P is a pointer to 2x2 array of pointers to a function with 2 type int parameters, that returns a int type pointer. Is this correct?

Comment: this is why I like delegates haha

Comment: Writing code like that in a real program, without any typedefs, should be made criminal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`cdecl`](http://cdecl.org/) is a great tool for figuring these kinds of problems out:

```
$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain int *(*(*P)[2][2])(int,int);
declare P as pointer to array 2 of array 2 of pointer to function (int, int) returning pointer to int
```

So yes, you're correct.

Comment: Another question (that i will be sure i understood), each cell is a pointer to different functions that receive 2 integers and return int* ?